# Creating a file within Python 2 script to write to , using argv

Tags: python, argv, sys

I want to use argv to create a file using the command line (example >>> python thisscript.py nonexistent.txt ) then write to it from within my code. I've used the open(nonexistent, 'w').write() command but it seems I can only open and write to files that already exist. Am I missing something?

This is my code. It works as long as the file I'm trying to write to already exists

```
from sys import argv



script, letter_file = argv



string_let='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

list_of_letters = list(string_let)


f = open(letter_file)


wf = open(letter_file, 'w')



def write_func():
        for j in range(26):

                for i in list_of_letters:

                        wf.write(i)



write_func()

wf.close()



raw_input('Press <ENTER> to read contents of %r' % letter_file)


output = f.read()


print output
```

But when the file does not aleady exist this is what I get returned to me in the terminal

```
[admin@horriblehost-mydomain ~]$ python alphabetloop.py nonexistent.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alphabetloop.py", line 14, in <module>
    f = open(letter_file)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nonexistent.txt'
[admin@horriblehost-mydomain ~]$
```

Comment: Please give us more information. And some code to get a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open(filename, 'w')` is not only for existing files. If the file doesn't exist, it will create it:

```
$ ls mynewfile.txt
ls: mynewfile.txt: No such file or directory
$ python
>>> with open("mynewfile.txt", "w") as f:
...     f.write("Foo Bar!")
... 
>>> exit()
$ cat mynewfile.txt 
Foo Bar!
```

Note that `'w'` will always wipe out the existing contents of the file. If you want to append to the end of an existing file or create the file if it doesn't exist, use `'a'` (i.e., `open("mynewfile.txt", "a")`)

Comment: I've edited my question to provide more details... open("mynewfile.txt", "w") doesn't create a nonexistent file for me, I've provided the terminal output as well.

Comment: Your error is for the file you are trying to open in *read* mode, which must exist. Opening a file in *write* mode will create it.

Comment: Yes, when you say `open(letter_file)`, that essentially means `open(letter_file, 'r')` because the default is to read a file if not specified. If `letter_file` doesn't exist, it's this call that fails.

Comment: Note that you don't need to open it in read mode before you've created it. Just write to it, close it, then reopen it to read.

Comment: @Jake Griffin I just changed it now, moving it to after I closed the file... oops.Thank you guys, it works now... I try to 'upvote' your answer , but it won't let me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv)<3:
    print "usage: makefile <filename> <content>"
else:
    open(sys.argv[1],'w').write(sys.argv[2])
```

demo:

```
paul@home:~/SO/py1$ python makefile.py ./testfile feefiefoefum
paul@home:~/SO/py1$ ls
makefile.py  makefile.py~  testfile
paul@home:~/SO/py1$ cat testfile 
feefiefoefum
```

Note:  in `sys.argv`, element `[0]` is the name of the script, and subsequent elements contain user input

Comment: I would change it so you could write `<content>` with spaces. For example, `paul@home:~/SO/py1$ python makefile.py ./testfile fee fie foe fum`, I was thinking of looping, but there might be an easier way

Comment: Eh, that works if you quote it.  "fee fie foe fum"  Try it.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a file with the 'w' flag, you will overwrite the contents of the file.  If the file does not exist, it will create it for you.

If what you would like to do is append to the file, you should open it with the "a" flag.

Here is an example:

```
with open("existing.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write("foo")  # overwrites anything inside the file
```

`existing.txt` now contains "foo"

```
with open("existing.txt", "a") as f:
  f.write("bar")  # appends 'bar' to 'foo'
```

`existing.txt` now contains "foobar"

Also, if you're not familiar with the `with` statement I used above, you should [read up about it](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).  It is a safer way to open and close files using what is called a Context Manager.